# Why property "fill" is not working in IE 11

Tags: d3.js, internet-explorer-11

I am using D3 Charts for my implementation and I am internally using a property "fill" for applying color to particular object which renders in UI.

Actually, I have specified the height and width for this react object in class shape. The attributes are taken when it comes to Chrome and other browser but its not working for IE alone.

Example Code Snippet:

```
g.append("rect")
 .attr("x", "-20")
 .attr("y", "10")
 .attr("rx", "5")
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
 .attr("class", "shape")
 .attr('fill', "#e3e3e3")
```

Property fill is coming in DOM element but that is not getting applied to the object react.
Any comments please.

Comment: Please add information about the html element or svg element itself.

Comment: Without related html code, we can't reproduce and locate the issue. We need [a minimal, reproducible code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can run so that we can have a better understading of the issue and see how to help. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Actually, this a chat component code snippet in that I am trying to draw a rectangle in the middle. This is the code which works completely fine for chrome and other browsers but with respect to IE the class shape is not getting recognized. So I need to explicitly add height and width as propertu to make this fill work. Does SVG will not accept height and width from class for IE 11?

Comment: I fixed it by adding additional attribute of height and width but want to know if that height and width will not taken from class in IE browser.

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You can put your solution and mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information, but most likely you have a css style for the rectangle.

If you do, you have two options: First, you could modify the css. Second, you could use `style` which overwrites the css. Like this:

```
g.append("rect")
 .attr("x", "-20")
 .attr("y", "10")
 .attr("rx", "5")
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
 .attr("class", "shape")
 .style('fill', "#e3e3e3");
```

Comment: I tried adding style for fill but that was not working until I add the height and width explicitly in the attribute. But for other browsers the height width is take from the class shape.